# flex align working on local host but not on github

Tags: css, github, flexbox

https://github.com/ivi989/ivi989.github.io

So, when I open this on local host everything is centered. However if I open the same files on gitub  it is not. Button goes left. If I center the button the hr is no longer centered. If using flex for hr it disappears and when I get it back its all the way to the right and I cant get it back to center.

Can someone help pls?
Thank you.

Comment: 'run on github', how?

Comment: Oh sorry, open, not run.  ivi989.github.io

Comment: Seems centered here (ivi989.github.io that is). Perhaps a caching problem? <ctrl-F5> ?

Comment: nope, still not centered.

Comment: https://imgur.com/dwhtsIt

Comment: Which browser, on which platform, are you using? Ah, it works correct in Firefox, but the button goes to the left in Chrome (both in Windows 10).

Comment: There's a DIV with ID = `mc_embed_signup_scroll`, it has `text-align: left;` if I change that to `center` it works for me.

Comment: for me its not centered in firefox also

Comment: I looked at it with the developer tools, are you familiar with that? In Chrome (Windows) you open them with <F12>. You can inspect the button, and see why it goes to the left.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to fix it in dev tools. I tried what you said. It's still not centered with the hr. they don't look how they look local

Answer (score 2):

This

`<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

What actually happening is that when you open your index.html the above mentioned css is not downloaded from internet instead it search for a file with the same name in your local system.When you open your index.html through git, https:// is appended with that link and thus your css is downloaded and your button is aligned left.

**Solution**

Add this style="text-align:center" to your div with this id="mc_embed_signup_scroll"

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" style="text-align:center">
```